# Using on('click') instead of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After it being suggested I make a more targeted question, I have this issue.

Currently I have this code

```
omShortcodes.modules.toggle = {
init: function() {

jQuery('.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle').addClass('omsc-in-accordion').find('.omsc-toggle-title').click(function(){

    var $toggle=jQuery(this).parent();

    if($toggle.hasClass('omsc-expanded')) {
        $toggle.removeClass('omsc-expanded');
        $toggle.find('.omsc-toggle-inner').slideUp(300);
        return false;
    }

    var $acc=$toggle.parents('.omsc-accordion');
    if(!$acc.hasClass('omsc-multiopen'))
        $acc.find('.omsc-toggle.omsc-expanded').removeClass('omsc-expanded').find('.omsc-toggle-inner').slideUp(300);

    $toggle.find('.omsc-toggle-inner').slideDown(300,function(){
        var h=jQuery(this).parent().height();
        var pos=jQuery(this).parent().find('.omsc-toggle-title').offset();
        var scroll=jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var wh=jQuery(window).height();
        if(pos.top < scroll || (pos.top > scroll && pos.top+h > scroll+wh))
            jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: pos.top+'px' }, 200);
    }).find('iframe[src*="maps.google"]').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('src',jQuery(this).attr('src'));
    });
    $toggle.addClass('omsc-expanded');

});

jQuery('.omsc-toggle').not('.in-accordion').find('.omsc-toggle-title').click(function(){

    var $toggle=jQuery(this).parent();

    var $inner=$toggle.find('.omsc-toggle-inner');
    if(!$inner.length)
        return false;
    if($inner.is(':animated'))
        return false;

    $toggle.toggleClass('omsc-expanded');
    $inner.slideToggle(300);
    if($toggle.hasClass('omsc-expanded')) {
        $inner.find('iframe[src*="maps.google"]').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr('src',jQuery(this).attr('src'));
        });
    }

    return false;
    });

   }
   }
```

But it doesn't work with AJAX, only when the page is loaded directly.

I've been advised to use on('click') instead of click.

I have tried

```
        jQuery('.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle').addClass('omsc-in-accordion').find('.omsc-toggle-title').on('click', '.omsc-accordion', function(){

        jQuery('.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle').addClass('omsc-in-accordion').find('.omsc-toggle-title').on('click', 'omsc-accordion', function(){

        jQuery('.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle').addClass('omsc-in-accordion').find('.omsc-toggle-title').on('click', '.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle', function(){
```

But all three make it do nothing at all. Am I implementing this incorrectly?

Comment: I don't see any ajax in that code.

Comment: Those elements may not exist on the page.  Try something like `$(document).on("click", ".omsc-accordian', function() { alert("hi");});`  Also, see the documentation for the `on` method: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Your code says attach an event to `.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle` and listen for a child element that is `omsc-accordion`.

Comment: Minor point - about a year ago I learned that you use ".click" for elements already in the DOM (static) and you need to use ".on('click' for elements you add to the DOM ('dynamic'). But since then I've learned that jQuery ".click" is derived directly from '.on('click' - and that there are other jQuery commands that are similarly derived.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('.omsc-toggle').not('.in-accordion').find('.omsc-toggle-title').click` will only attach the click handler to the events that exist when the page loads. To attach the handler to future elements, use the delegation features of `on`.

```
jQuery('#container').on('click', '.omsc-toggle:not(.in-accordion) .omsc-toggle-title', function() {
  console.log('clicked!');
});
```

where `#container` is the element that contains all of your `.omsc-toggle` elements. It is not recommended to attach event handlers to `$(document)`.

Comment: Thanks. Although adding that code in does not showed up as clicked in the console at all, even when the accordion is working from a direct page view (I've succesfully logged 'clicked' from the original method)